# can't find referenced component for F# library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, f#

I'm doing some work with a pretty old C#/F# library and the code is trying to import Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Types.BigInt which from which I've gathered is in the FSharp.PowerPack.dll. Though even when I browse manually to add the reference it still says that the reference can't be found. It's in the FSharpPowerPack-4.0 folder and the target framework is .NET Framework 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biginteger type has moved around a bit since the early days of F#.  The easiest thing for you to do would be to add your own file like so

```
module Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Types
type BigInt = Microsoft.FSharp.Core.bigint
```

and then just get that to compile before everything else.

This creates a type alias to the new location